# Загрузить файлы поместить в zip?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Мне нужно зарузить файлы, допустим мне надо принять несколько файлов file1,file2....,добавить их в список(List files = new ArrayList<>()),а после пройтись по списку и каждый добавить в zip,а этот zip конвертировать в формат MultipartFile и сохранить в базу)Помогите не могу понять как файлы засунуть в zip  ?

```
@Controller
    public class AttachmentController {
    
        private AttachmentService attachmentService;
    
    
    
        public AttachmentController(AttachmentService attachmentService) {
            this.attachmentService = attachmentService;
        }
    
    
        @PostMapping("/upload")
        public String uploadFile(@RequestParam String title, @RequestParam String author,@RequestParam("file")MultipartFile file1) throws Exception {
            Attachment attachment = null;
            
            attachment = attachmentService.saveAttachment(title,author,file1);
    
            return "redirect:/";
    
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/download/{fileId}")
        public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFile(@PathVariable String fileId) throws Exception {
            Attachment attachment = null;
            attachment = attachmentService.getAttachment(fileId);
            return  ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(attachment.getFileType()))
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                            "attachment; filename=\"" + attachment.getFileName()
                    + "\"")
                    .body(new ByteArrayResource(attachment.getData()));
        }
```

Сервис

```
 @Service
    public class AttachmentServiceImpl implements AttachmentService{
    
        private AttachmentRepository attachmentRepository;
    
        public AttachmentServiceImpl(AttachmentRepository attachmentRepository) {
            this.attachmentRepository = attachmentRepository;
        }
    
    
    
        @Override
        public Attachment saveAttachment(String title,String author,MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
           String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
           try {
                if(fileName.contains("..")) {
                    throw  new Exception("Filename contains invalid path sequence "
                    + fileName);
                }
    
                Attachment attachment
                        = new Attachment(title,author,fileName,
                        file.getContentType(),
                        file.getBytes());
                return attachmentRepository.save(attachment);
    
           } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new Exception("Could not save File: " + fileName);
           }
        }
        
    
    
        @Override
        public Attachment getAttachment(String fileId) throws Exception {
            return attachmentRepository
                    .findById(fileId)
                    .orElseThrow(
                            () -> new Exception("File not found with Id: " + fileId));
        }
```

Comment: простите, а почему вы решили что вам не подходит зип (для сохранения в бд он действительно не подходит, но и мультипарт не подходит, и в целом сохранения файла в бд - плохая идея)? и второй вопрос: а вы пробовали заглянуть в сорцы мультипарт, чтобы понять что это вообще(если что - спринг и меет открытый исходный код)?

Comment: непонятно, что именно вы хотите "обойти".  я не вижу ваш класс Attachment , но, судя по конструктору, он уже содержит массив байтов, а значит файл, представленный в виде этого массива, уже может быть сохранен в бд (другой вопрос, что это не лучшее решение, но технически это возможно). ваш сервис создает экземпляр этого класса (Attachment ) и через репозиторий сохраняет его в бд. Тогда в чем именно ваша проблема?